# Show using duality that exactly one of the following systems has a solution

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

(I) $Ax=b$ ;  $0≤ x ≤e$

(II) $uA +v ≥0  ;  ub + ve = -1  ;  v ≥ 0$

Comment: How we prove it by duality?

Comment: What do you mean by $e$?

Comment: e is any positive value just like b..

Answer (score 0):

we make an LP min 0x s.t Ax=b , x ≤e , x ≥ 0  while the dual of this LP is max ub + vc s.t   uA+ v ≤ 0 , v≤0.
Is it a right approach to prove the above systems.

Please guide me that how i can prove that the exactally one system has a solution by duality.

Thanks